# No module named `pptx`

Tags: python-3.x, python-pptx

I try to import pptx (`from pptx import Presentation`) and get message "No module named pptx".
I've installed pptx (`pip install python-pptx`).
Running `pip show python-pptx`,  I get:

`Name: python-pptx
Version: 0.6.18
Summary: Generate and manipulate Open XML PowerPoint (.pptx) files
Home-page: http://github.com/scanny/python-pptx
Author: Steve Canny
Author-email: python-pptx@googlegroups.com
License: The MIT License (MIT)
Location: c:\users\sheshe~1\appdata\local\r-mini~1\lib\site-packages
Requires: Pillow, lxml, XlsxWriter
Required-by:`

Could you help me? What should I do else to import pptx?

Comment: Hi Marry, welcome to StackOverflow :) Have you tried search? This question has been asked and answered several times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this,

Using pip install, you'll install it for Python2, not for Python3. To make sure it gets installed for Python3, invoke pip from the interpreter, like this:

```
python3 -m pip install <package>
```

Hope this helps you.